# Android, how can i get a row of a listview and send to other tab?

Tags: android, tabs, wifi

Ive got a scan scanning for wifi networks in a listview in tab1. So when i click on a network i want to go to tab2 and display the clicked network but more advanced information about it.

How can i send the name of the netowrk(ssid) to the other tab and then only list the choosen network in tab2?

```
public class Tab1 extends TabActivity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    String ssid;
    int channel;
    int level;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> wifis;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;
    TabHost tabHost;

    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String TAB1 = "Tab1";
    private static final String TAB2 = "Tab2";
    private static final String TAB3 = "Tab3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);
        tabHost = new TabHost(this);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        wifis = new ArrayList<String>(); //initialize wifis
        wifis.add("loading...");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        wifiManager.startScan(); //make sure this is the last call
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

            }
        }); }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public static int convertFrequencyToChannel(int freq) {
        if (freq >= 2412 && freq <= 2484) {
            return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
        } else if (freq >= 5170 && freq <= 5825) {
            return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }


    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            wifis.clear(); //add this
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID; //Get the SSID
                level = wifiScanList.get(i).level;
                channel = wifiScanList.get(i).frequency;

                //use add here:
                wifis.add(ssid + " " + level + " dBm "); //append to the other data
                wifis.toString();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this
            wifiManager.startScan(); //start a new scan to update values faster

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your value from one tab to another tab or from tab activity to tab.like below

```
//Create the public static reference of TabHost and intent  in your TabActivity. i.e 

    public static TabHost tabHost;
    public static Intent intent;
    //in TabActivity initialize it inside OnCreate 
    tabHost = getTabHost();       
    intent =getIntent();
    //now inside listitem click pass the values like
    YourTabActivity.intent.putExtra("listvalue","your list value");
    YourTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    //now inside the other tabs override the OnResume method to get the value and update your UI
     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String value = YourTabActivity.intent
                .getStringExtra("listvalue");
        if (null != value)
            //use this value :)
    }
```